# How does Gazebo's physics engine simulate flight of a drone or an UAV?

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu, px4

ODE is the default physics engine of Gazebo that solves the equation of motion. But how is flight simulated though, which plugins does it use to simulate rotor dynamics. Because ODE isn't suitable for accurate and precise flight dynamics (compared to JSBSim or a 6DoF solver that uses aerodynamics lookup table, I tried to find some research article that benchmarks ODE in terms of accuracy and stability against accurate computational Flight dynamics models but came across empty thus far....the benchmark analyses I found were against similar engines targeted at games for multi articulated systems, ground dynamics, but not for flight.